# Validate that the .exe file exists at the given path

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java and Eclipse. It would be great if someone could help me with the following question.

I am using a `.exe` file to run a piece of my code. Even if I give a different location for the `.exe` file the Java program runs; however it does not use the `.exe` file and displays wrong results.

I was wondering how could I validate that the same `.exe` file exists at the path given in input?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly.  Are you asking how to verify if a particular file exists?

```
File f = new File(path);
if (f.exists()) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!Yes, i need to check if a particular .exe file exsits at the given location.